# how to add another 0000n_initial.py file from makemigrations command

Tags: django

i want to add another initial.py file from makemigrations file

when i try to py manage.py makemigrations it show error

> > you are trying to add a non-nullable field 'role' to user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
> >
> > Please select a fix :
> >
> > 1. Provide a one-off default now(will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
> > 2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

i want to make another init to make a dependent dropdown

this is what i write in models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class TableAll(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

and this is the code that 0001_initial.py has

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.2 on 2019-10-29 03:52

from django.db import migrations, models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    role = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    role.contribute_to_class(User,'role')    

    operations = [

        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TableAll',
            fields=[                
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('table_name', models.CharField(max_length=250)),                
            ],
        ),

    ]
```

i want to add a foreign key to another model and want to makemigrations to add a new 00002_initial.py(for example) and i want to have something like this(here is the code i found from github source)

new initial file (0002_add_initial_data.py) //this is just an example from github source code where it has 0001_initial.py and 0002_add_initial_data.py to make the dependent dropdown works

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    Country = apps.get_model('hr', 'Country')
    City = apps.get_model('hr', 'City')

    india = Country.objects.create(name='India')
    City.objects.create(name='Bengaluru', country=india)
    City.objects.create(name='Mumbai', country=india)
    City.objects.create(name='Chennai', country=india)
    City.objects.create(name='Hyderabad', country=india)
    City.objects.create(name='New Delhi', country=india)

    usa = Country.objects.create(name='United States')
    City.objects.create(name='New York', country=usa)
    City.objects.create(name='San Francisco', country=usa)
    City.objects.create(name='Los Angeles', country=usa)
    City.objects.create(name='Chicago', country=usa)
    City.objects.create(name='Seattle', country=usa)

    russia = Country.objects.create(name='Russia')
    City.objects.create(name='Moscow', country=russia)
    City.objects.create(name='Saint Petersburg', country=russia)
    City.objects.create(name='Yekaterinburg', country=russia)
    City.objects.create(name='Kazan', country=russia)
    City.objects.create(name='Krasnodar', country=russia)

    brazil = Country.objects.create(name='Brazil')
    City.objects.create(name='Sao Paulo', country=brazil)
    City.objects.create(name='Rio de Janeiro', country=brazil)
    City.objects.create(name='Belo Horizonte', country=brazil)
    City.objects.create(name='Curitiba', country=brazil)
    City.objects.create(name='Recife', country=brazil)

    uk = Country.objects.create(name='United Kingdom')
    City.objects.create(name='London', country=uk)
    City.objects.create(name='Huddersfield', country=uk)
    City.objects.create(name='Glasgow', country=uk)
    City.objects.create(name='Edinburgh', country=uk)
    City.objects.create(name='Cambridge', country=uk)

    dependencies = [
        ('hr', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_initial_data),
    ]
```

Thankyou for the help, im new to this django framework , and i need to use it for my thesis ..

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern that can be followed when a non-nullable field is being added to a model and the value of that field is the result of a script.

1. Add the field to your model but make it nullable (null=True)
2. Run makemigrations to create a migration that adds the nullable field
3. Create another migration (makemigrations  --empty) that fills in this column using `migrations.RunPython`
4. Remove null=True from the field and run makemigrations again. When prompted with the selection choose 1 "Provide a one-off default now" and enter any integer you like as all rows should already have a value it will not matter
5. migrate